# Double bottom line on first item of list in Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm creating a list in Ionic 5 by reiterating the items of an array. But the first item on the list keeps getting 2 bottom lines on the Android rendering. This is my code:

```
<ion-list class="ion-padding" inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let recurrent of myRecentRecurrents" [routerLink]="['/tabs/recorrente', recurrent.id]">
        <p>{{ recurrent.plan.amount }}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

This is the expected result:
[image: Ionic 5 list]

But this is what I get:
[image: Notice the double line on the first item]

Does someone know why I'm getting this result?

https://codepen.io/mfragale/pen/YzyNrvq

Comment: There is a style present for inset lists on android. 
.list-md.list-inset ion-item:first-child It adds a border on the first ion-item which is causing this

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `inset` attribute from the `ion-list` and add `lines="inset"` to each `ion-item`, i.e.

```
<ion-list class="ion-padding">
    <ion-item *ngFor="..." lines="inset">
        ...
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

See the [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item) for more.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the list is not inset anymore.